# How to remove year from Highchart

Tags: javascript, highcharts

i am very new to use Highchart

http://jsfiddle.net/ktmfy6qe/1/ Here i want to remove **year** listening. first i want listen **old data** (
`name: 'Random data',
 data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]`) after that directly listen **current time** **without showing year.** Please help me to remove year.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use xAxis-> labels -> formatter function to foramt the date as you want.

Here in your case since you have not mentioned the start of the time and interval for those value , Library started the plotting from its default values.

now the same way as you did for the tooltip you can do formatting for labels as well

```
xAxis: {
    type: 'datetime',
    tickPixelInterval: 150,
    labels: {
        formatter: function() {
            console.log(Highcharts.dateFormat('%H:%M:%S', this.value))
            return  Highcharts.dateFormat('%H:%M:%S', this.value)
        }
    }
},
```

[here](http://jsfiddle.net/ktmfy6qe/2/) is the fiddle

Comment: Thank You @strikers its works. is it any possible to directly listen current time after listening old data.